# Flutter: one of two streambuilder not loaded

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two streams fetching from different api.

```dart
Stream<List<dynamic>> get getMessage => _messageController.stream;
Stream<List<String>> get getUser => _userController.stream;
```

I'm trying to fetch these data at different state of the application.

```dart
  Stream<List<dynamic>> _fetchStream(String roomId) {
    return Stream<List<dynamic>>.fromFuture(ChatService.fetch(roomId));
  }

  Future<List<String>> _fetchUserList(String roomId) async {
    Chatroom roomInfo =
        Chatroom.fromJson(await ChatroomService.getRoomInfo(roomId));
    _users = roomInfo.users;
    return roomInfo.users;
  }
```

My screen has streambuilders as

```dart
return Scaffold(
      endDrawer: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const DrawerHeader(child: Text('Header')),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: _streamSocket.getUser,
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                } else {
                  _streamSocket.users = snapshot.data!;
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      String user = snapshot.data![index];
                      return Text(user);
                    },
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: _streamSocket.getMessage,
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else {
                _streamSocket.messages = snapshot.data!;
                return Positioned(
                  top: 0,
                  bottom: 60,
                  width: size.width,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    reverse: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      Message message = Message.fromJson(
                          snapshot.data![snapshot.data!.length - index - 1]);
                      return MessageItem(
                        message: message,
                        isUserMessage: message.isUserMessage(widget.user),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
```

The problem is streambuilder which has `_streamSocket.getUser` not loaded infinitely, while below one works well. Api call itself does not matter. It actually stored in `_users` properly. Do I missing anything while handling two streams?

Comment: please include a complete example, as others will be able to help you more accurately. The snippet should be runnable